# batch script path display

Tags: windows, batch-file, path, display

I have a problem with a batch file.
I write @echo off at the start but cmd appears.
also the path appears each every line.
The code looks like:

```
@echo off
netsh interface ipv4 show interface
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="LAN-Verbindung" source=dhcp
echo  DONE!
pause
```

This is my cmd output:
[image: This is my cmd output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a proper editor to create your batch code, not a word-processor. I use EDITPLUS, others use NOTEPAD++.

At a pinch, use NOTEPAD.

Your problem is that there is a character or set of characters before the `@` in your file. This may be because the file is UNICODE, but it should be saved as ANSI.

Also - to format code, select it and press the `{}` button which will indent the code 4 spaces which indicates it is code.

Do not post links to your results as these are outside of SE and not available for future reference. You can include a file in your post by using the Icon that looks like a view of mountains with the sun.